# AJAX call on .net server to run code on Coldfusion server and get results?

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, coldfusion

In my head, this works, but I am not getting a 'success' result, so I have to ask:

**Can I run an AJAX call to a Coldfusion server/page, and get the results on my .net server?**

I found some posts online about using 'JSONP' instead of 'JSON', but I do not get any results back. Not even console.log() outputs anything from the 'success' for the AJAX call, although I do get a '200 OK' message in the console.

---

If the answer to my question above is, "Yes", here is my call. What am I doing wrong?

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://otherserveraddress.com/search/searchresults.cfm',
                datatype: 'jsonp',
                data: {q: 'testQuery', s: 0},
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log('was successful...');
                    $('#search-results').html('test');
                }
            });
```

And here is the important stuff from my Coldfusion file. Note I found the 'serializeToJSONP function online through Google search.

```
<cfparam name="output" default="" />
<cfif hasResults>
<!--- loop through results --->
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#ArrayLen(resultNodes)#">
<cfset result = resultNodes[i] />
<cfset url = result['U'] />
<cfset title = result['T'] />
<cfset description = result['S'] />

<cfscript>
  output &= '<h3><a href="' & #url.XmlText# & '">' & #title.XmlText# & '</a></h3>
  <p>'
     & #description.XmlText# & '<br />'
    & #url.XmlText# & '<br /><br />
  </p>';
</cfscript>

</cfloop>

<cfoutput>#serializeToJSONP(output, "runit")#</cfoutput>

<cffunction name="serializeToJSONP" displayname="Serialize to JSONp" hint="Serializes supplied data in JSONp format" output="false" returntype="any">
<cfargument name="data" displayName="data" type="any" hint="The data to serialize" required="true" />
<cfargument name="callback" displayName="callback" type="string" hint="the jsonp callback to use" required="true" />

<cfscript>
var local = {};
local.json = serializeJSON(arguments.data);
local.jsonp = arguments.callback & '(' & local.json & ')';
</cfscript>

<cfreturn local.jsonp />
```

Comment: Have a look at [CORS](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) rather than JSONP if you own the server. JSONP uses script tags to fulfill requests and is far less flexible than usual ajax requests.

Comment: where is your "runit" function in the calling code?

Comment: That's a good question. The webpage from which I grabbed that function had the example CF call, but not the AJAX call. How should I call that?

Comment: Do you have `cfcontent` any were in your cfm? I think jQuery may have an issue parsing the response if it's being return as text/html and declared jsonp. Also have you tried adding an error handler to the ajax call?

Comment: Side note: though not technically required, typically you would use a remote .cfc, rather than .cfm script for this kind of thing. Among other reasons, it can help avoid problems with white space issues.

Comment: (Edit) If it's just a regular ajax call from one server to another, the server side languages involved do not matter. As long as the scripts return the correct js/json to the browser it will work. Couple suggestions: a) You might want to try a simple, hard coded example first, just to get a handle on how JSONP works first b) Check firebird, or whatever debugging tool you are using for errors c) In addition to the comment about headers, I am not sure I follow your CF code ... What is `resultNodes` and where is it defined? (Also, `URL` is a reserved word. Best not to use it as a variable name).